# How to add a marker in a map? i using SupportMapFragment

Tags: xamarin.android, google-maps-markers, supportmapfragment

This is my code,
I am trying to add a bookmark to google maps, and also to initialize the map in a specific place, but I can not understand how SupporMapFragment works, if someone could help me explaining how to do it, thanks

```
    internal class DetailMapFragment : BaseFragment , IOnMapReadyCallback
            {
                private GoogleMap GoogleMap;
                private SupportMapFragment _mapFragment;

                public override int LayoutId => Resource.Layout.map_page;
                protected override void InitViews()
                {
                    //var mapView = mView.FindViewById<MapView>(Resource.Id.mapView);
                    //mapView.GetMapAsync(this);
                    try
                    {
                        _mapFragment = Activity.SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag("map") as SupportMapFragment;

                        if (_mapFragment == null)
                        {
                            GoogleMapOptions mapOptions = new GoogleMapOptions()
                                .InvokeMapType(GoogleMap.MapTypeNormal)
                                .InvokeZoomControlsEnabled(false)
                                .InvokeMaxZoomPreference(20)
                                .InvokeCompassEnabled(true);

                            FragmentTransaction fragTx = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                            _mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.NewInstance(mapOptions);
                            fragTx.Add(Resource.Id.mapView, _mapFragment, "map");
                            fragTx.Commit();


 LatLng latlong = new LatLng(40.776408,-73.970755);
                    MarkerOptions mark = new MarkerOptions()
                        .SetPosition(latlong)
                        .SetTitle("New York")
                        .SetSnippet("Apple");
                    _mapFragment.AddMarker(mark);


      }
                    _mapFragment.GetMapAsync(this);
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.Message.ToString();
                }
   public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
        {
            //this.GoogleMap = googleMap;
        }
        void IOnMapReadyCallback.OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
        {
            //try
            //{
            //    this.GoogleMap = googleMap;
            //    if (googleMap != null)
            //    {
            //        googleMap.AnimateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLng(new LatLng(-11.083271, -76.207374)));
            //    }
            //}
            //catch (System.Exception ex)
            //{
            //    ex.Message.ToString();
            //}
        }
      }
```

i new in xamarin android, i cant achieved understand how add de marker to map

Comment: I didnt understand what you meant by loading your map in a specific place.

Answer (score 1):

Its very easy actually all you have to do is the following:

- In your variable of type, Google maps in your case this `private GoogleMap GoogleMap;`you need to add the markers
- Now adding markers can be tricky as you need to add them not when your google map object is null and this object gets its value runtime, so you need to be sure that it's not null because if it is then your app will crash for sure
  (If not handled).
- What i do for this case is always null check before adding a marker, and since it is bitmap(Which is the main reason for a thousand types of memory leaks in Android usually),On destroy of my map fragment i call the garbage collector and i clear my google maps object by calling `GoogleMap.Clear();` whenever i leave the maps page.
- Coming to the point the code for adding markers is as follows:

  ```
                  LatLng latlngall = new LatLng(double.Parse(point.Latitude), double.Parse(point.Loungitude));
                  MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().SetPosition(latlngall).SetTitle(point.Landmark);
                  options.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.marker));
                  Marker marker = GMap.AddMarker(options);
                  marker.Tag = point.Id.ToString();
  ```
- Here you need latitude, longitude and a title for your marker, also if you want to provide your custom marker then you can put it in place of the `Drawable.marker` also lat and long are mandatory here.

In case you have any other problems revert here.

Goodluck!
Happy coding